Xcode 15 RN 0.59 error: UIViewController is missing its initial trait collection populated during initialization
I'm maintaining a legacy app built with React Native. I can build it, and the app opens without issues on both iOS 16 and iOS 17 devices. The problem occurs when I try to log in. On the iOS 16 device, when I click the login button, I'm directed to the home screen, which is the expected behavior. On the iOS 17 device, the following error occurs. I've been researching for days and can't find anything to help me deal with this problem. I know it's a complicated situation because it's a very old version of React Native, but currently, updating is not an option. I appreciate anyone who can help.
Erro
enter image description here
Exception 'UIViewController is missing its initial trait collection populated during initialization. This is a serious bug, likely caused by accessing properties or methods on the view controller before calling a UIViewController initializer. View controller: <RNNSideMenuController: 0x7f8b5e30a200>' was thrown while invoking setRoot on target RNNBridgeModule with params (
    setRoot7,
        {
        modals =         (
        );
        overlays =         (
        );
        root =         {
            children =             (
                                {
                    children =                     (
                                                {
                            children =                             (
                            );
                            data =                             {
                                name = "ssgapp.Menu";
                                options =                                 {
                                };
                            };
                            id = Drawer;
                            type = Component;
                        }
                    );
                    data =                     {
                    };
                    id = SideMenuLeft5;
                    type = SideMenuLeft;
                },
                                {
                    children =                     (
                                                {
                            children =                             (
                                                                {
                                    children =                                     (
                                    );
                                    data =                                     {
                                        name = "ssgapp.Dashboard";
                                        options =                                         {
                                            topBar =                                             {
                                                background =                                                 {
                                                    color = 0;
                                                };
                                                drawBehind = 1;
                                                elevation = 0;
                                                leftButtons =                                                 (
                                                                                                        {
                                                        color = 4294967295;
                                                        icon =                                                         {
                                                            scale = 3;
                                                            uri = "/Users/sysmap/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/164CD310-F4A4-42B0-BE4F-310F5C8AEF7B/data/Containers/Data/Application/EA54EBF0-86E2-4B2B-97E3-98ECEA57A62D/tmp/RNVectorIcons__Ionicons_61891_30#000000@3x.png";
                                                        };
                                                        id = menuToggleButton;
                                                    }
                                                );
                                                rightButtons =                                                 (
                                                                                                        {
                                                        color = 553648127;
                                                        enabled = 0;
                                                        icon =                                                         {
                                                            scale = 3;
                                                            uri = "/Users/sysmap/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/164CD310-F4A4-42B0-BE4F-310F5C8AEF7B/data/Containers/Data/Application/EA54EBF0-86E2-4B2B-97E3-98ECEA57A62D/tmp/RNVectorIcons__Ionicons_61826_30#000000@3x.png";
                                                        };
                                                        id = filterToggleButton;
                                                    }
                                                );
                                                title =                                                 {
                                                    color = 4294967295;
                                                    component =                                                     {
                                                        alignment = center;
                                                        componentId = CustomComponent8;
                                                    };
                                                    fontFamily = DINPro;
                                                    text = "Pend\U00eancias";
                                                };
                                            };
                                        };
                                    };
                                    id = App;
                                    type = Component;
                                }
                            );
                            data =                             {
                            };
                            id = AppRoot;
                            type = Stack;
                        }
                    );
                    data =                     {
                    };
                    id = SideMenuCenter6;
                    type = SideMenuCenter;
                }
            );
            data =             {
                options =                 {
                    layout =                     {
                        orientation =                         (
                            portrait
                        );
                    };
                    topBar =                     {
                        background =                         {
                            color = 0;
                        };
                        drawBehind = 1;
                        elevation = 0;
                    };
                };
            };
            id = sideMenu;
            type = SideMenuRoot;
        };
    },
    560,
    561
)
callstack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6c4571 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010aaff7e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00000001103b878b -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) classForCoder] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122c70299 UIViewControllerMissingInitialTraitCollection + 215
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122c75006 -[UIViewController traitCollection] + 168
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122c7c9f7 -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:] + 263
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000122c7cd02 -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 629
    7   ssgapp                              0x000000010097d934 -[RNNSideMenuController setControllers:] + 628
    8   ssgapp                              0x000000010097cfa0 -[RNNSideMenuController initWithLayoutInfo:creator:childViewControllers:options:defaultOptions:presenter:eventEmitter:] + 272
    9   ssgapp                              0x000000010095f857 -[RNNControllerFactory createSideMenu:] + 391
    10  ssgapp                              0x000000010095e9f3 -[RNNControllerFactory fromTree:] + 451
    11  ssgapp                              0x000000010095e538 -[RNNControllerFactory createLayout:] + 72
    12  ssgapp                              0x0000000100958c99 -[RNNCommandsHandler setRoot:commandId:completion:] + 1209
    13  ssgapp                              0x00000001009564d4 -[RNNBridgeModule setRoot:layout:resolver:rejecter:] + 308
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6cb19c __invoking___ + 140
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6c84c3 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 302
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6c8733 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 70
    17  ssgapp                              0x00000001007f7e20 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2528
    18  ssgapp                              0x000000010088533b _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 731
    19  ssgapp                              0x0000000100884eb2 _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 98
    20  ssgapp                              0x0000000100884e49 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 25
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af683ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af696d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af7848c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1420
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af77ef2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b620b34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b61b46f __CFRunLoopRun + 2463
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b61a6ed CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011672e08f GSEventRunModal + 137
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001236616ee -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    30  UIKitCore                           0x000000012366616e UIApplicationMain + 1

RCTFatal
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0


Mac Configuration
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 14.4.1
      CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
      Memory: 85.22 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.20.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.22 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 23.5, iOS 17.5, macOS 14.5, tvOS 17.5, visionOS 1.2, watchOS 10.5
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 15.4/15F31d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9

Depedencies
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-currency-formatter": "1.1.0",
    "react-moment": "0.8.4",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.3.3",
    "react-native-camera": "1.4.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "1.5.22",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "1.2.5",
    "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "2.6.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-navigation": "2.21.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "3.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "0.3.4",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "0.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "eslint": "4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.9.1",
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.6",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "2.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "2.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.3"
  },
}

I tried to do the process in Xcode 15.3 and used yarn install --ignore-engines.
